# Magento Mage not working as expected from external php file

Tags: php, magento, mage

I have an external php file that I call using ajax on Magento register page. This php code should help validate if the value of a text input field is valid. See php code:

```
require_once ('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app()->getStore();
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
$request = Mage::app()->getRequest();
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
$inviteCode = $request->getParam('code');

if (($inviteCode) && ($inviteCode != '')) {
        $websiteId = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();
        $customerId = $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId)->loadByEmail($inviteCode)->getId();

        if ($customerId && ($customerId != '')) {
                $account = Mage::getModel('affiliateplus/account')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customerId)->getFirstItem();

                if ($account && ($account->getAccountId())) {   
                 $result = "Valid Invite Code";
                } 
        }
}

//echo json_encode($result);
echo ($account );
```

I have a multiple website installation. This code sits in a addon domain hosted in a subfolder yyy.

1. `$websiteId` should return "5" (xxx.com/yyy), but it keeps returning "1" (xxx.com).
2. If I manually set `$websiteId` to "5", `$account` returns empty value

The code works fine in a model function. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to locate the `app/Mage.php` file and require it in your php file.
require_once '`app/Mage.php`';

Add Below code in your php file:

```
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
if (!file_exists($mageFilename)) {
    echo $mageFilename." was not found";
    exit;
}
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::app();
```

Comment: I have require_once('app/Mage/php') at the beginning of the code...Mage::app()->getRequest() returns correct value, but Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId() returns the wrong value